# Does Sallen-Key filter need a high impedance load?

Tags: sallen-key

I am using the circuit below to monitor the output of a piezoelectric diaphragm, represented by a sine wave generator and capacitor C3.

The circuit is powered from a split supply (+5V/-5V) derived from a linear power supply (230V, 50Hz). I need the full rail-to-rail dynamic range (or as close as possible).

[image]

The functions of the amplifiers are as follows:

- U1 - charge amplifier, frequency range of interest: 1Hz-60Hz
- U2 - Sallen Key filter, low pass, fc = 110Hz
- U3 - scale and bias amplifier to convert U2 output to 0V min, +3V
  max, suitable for ADC.

The circuit works in simulation, but in practice I find that a high amplitude mechanical impulse on the piezoelectric disk causes U3 to oscillate'. (U3 seems to output the input plus narrow pulses which jump to the +5V rail at a frequency of 50Hz). The oscillation will eventually disappear (after about 30-40 seconds) if the piezo is left untouched. I checked the power supply rails - they are clean with little ripple, even when the oscillation is happening.

If I disconnect U3 and monitor the output of U2 only, the problem is not present. I found that I could "cure" the oscillation in the circuit by putting a voltage follower amplifier between U2 and U3 and then reconnecting U3. I'd prefer not to use a voltage follower op amp as it introduces additional noise.

My question is: ***Does U3 cause a problem for the stability of U2 at high frequencies?*** The impedance of C101 will be low for a high frequency impulse on the piezo disk and U2 is trying to drive current to support this as well as maintaining the correct current through R5 to keep the input voltages on pin 2 at around 1V d.c.

Perhaps there's a better way to offset the output signal?

Comment: I'd be worried about the output from the LMC6041. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Hi Andy. Thanks for your comment. The output from U1 seems stable. Please may I ask what worries you about it?  My understanding is that U1 follows a common charge amplifier design approach, similar to figure 3 in http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa033a/sloa033a.pdf       Would welcome your further thoughts on this.

Comment: What does your layout look like? How much capacitance do you have for power filter caps on each op amp? Do you have any large sources of parasitic inductance?

Comment: OK, you needed to prove it wasn't an upstream signal problem. Maybe a scope shot will help .

Comment: Thanks laptop2d. Still at the breadboard stage - I'm using 100nF ceramic disk to decouple between +5V & GND and -5V & GND. Plus a 10uF between +5V & GND where the supply is connected to the breadboard.
As far as parasitic inductance goes, I've tried to keep loops to a minimum. The leads from the power supply are about half a metre long (I could try taping them together, I guess). Yes, the +5 and -5V connections are connected to the board about 3 inches apart, on opposite sides of the op amps as that's how the op amp V+ and V- pins are arranged. I've tried to keep lead lengths short.

Comment: @Andyaka I'll go and see if I can reproduce the oscillation and post a trace here shortly. Is there an issue connecting the output of U1 directly to R101 (the resistor stage of the low pass filter)? I took the view that U1 had a low enough output impedance not to cause a problem.

Comment: @DB17 I just have a worry about the LMC's phase margin. It's not clear in the data sheet when 10 nF is feedbing back.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for taking the time to look at the data sheet. There _may_ be a bit of ringing on the output of U1 after a spike at the input, it's hard to tell with my test equipment. I'm not sure what I can do to improve the phase margin. I can put a guard ring round the pins on the final pcb but I'm not sure how much this will help. I believe 1nF through to 10nF feedback caps are common on charge amplifiers? I haven't seen any instability so far. Is there anything else I could do to improve phase margin?

Comment: Things you might try: These devices have poor power supply rejection at high frequencies so you will need to be especially careful with your power supply and ground lines near each of the amplifiers.  Especially you need ceramic capacitors between both power rails of U2 and C102-GND, and make sure the current path from the power supplies to U2 are separate from the other amplifiers.  You could also add a high-R bleed resistor in parallel with the piezo rather than leaving it floating.  Finally, you might add a small passive RC before the filter to knock out the really high frequencies.

Comment: @Andyaka. Here are some scope photographs (apologies for using Tinypic). I put the piezo on a sub-woofer speaker driven by a 16Hz tone.

These are the output signals as seen using by my DSO:

U1 pin 6 
http://i68.tinypic.com/4uclyq.jpg

 ** U3 pin 6
http://i68.tinypic.com/1f8iz9.jpg

 ** U2 pin 6
http://i64.tinypic.com/23hvpk6.jpg

 ** U2 pin 6 with R5 disconnected
http://i63.tinypic.com/34zjbwn.jpg

Comment: Thank you @JohnBirckhead for your advice. Actually the circuit diagram representation might be misleading. The piezo is actually connected between signal ground and R2. (Admittedly, it's connected to these points at the end of a 2m length of coaxial cable.) R2 and the piezo capacitance form a low pass filter of time constant Cp*R2, where Cp is the piezo capacitance (probably about 60nF). I could increase R2 to reduce the filter cut-off but I don't want to attenuate frequencies less than 60Hz. (1/2.pi.R2.Cp = 80Hz at the moment).

Comment: Ok, I’m not sure but I think there is somehow parasitic feedback in the final two stages. You are ok with the first stage it seems. Parasitic feedback could be via the power rails or some other coupling mechanism that I can’t fathom. If you can bypass the first stage and inject a pulse into R101 where it would connect to the first stage and see what happens.

Comment: @Andyaka, really appreciate your interest here (how do I 'upvote' your comments?). I'll try the test you suggested and report back here if I have any success. For completeness, I've managed to reproduce the U3 pin 6 output oscillation that I first saw and was trying to describe in my original post. I've uploaded the scope trace to http://i68.tinypic.com/vijmu8.jpg   After this oscillation has been triggered, U3 pin 6 eventually settles down to the waveform I posted earlier (http://i68.tinypic.com/1f8iz9.jpg)

Comment: Thanks to eveyone for their suggestions. After some experimentation, I haven't been able to solve the problem. I think I might try a non-CMOS op amp at position U1, one that has a greater bandwidth and a FET input. Looking at TLE2071CPE4 as a possibility (it has to be in a PDIP package for breadboard testing). It doesn't swing rail-to-rail but I may have to live with that.

Comment: Just to follow up. I changed my op amps from CMOS to FET input types. Specifically, I used AD820AN for the charge amplifier and Sallen Key filter. I changed U3 to a bipolar op amp part TLE2141IP. Both op amp types are low noise. The circuit now seems stable.